# How to call a method to every element in an array without iterating through it?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, optimization

I'm writing a small program in which I have an array of 25 dots. Each dot has its own position, size and colour, and as I'm using a graphics library (Allegro), I have a method to print them on the screen.

I need to print them at the same time, and using:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < m_size ; i++)
    {
        points[i].move();
        points[i].draw();
    }
```

Prints them one after the other. What definitely works better is:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < m_size ; i++)
    {
        points[0].move();
        points[0].draw();
        points[1].move();
        points[1].draw();

        // ...

        points[24].move();
        points[24].draw();
    }
```

Which of course is a far from optimal solution; but works perfectly. Question is, is there any way to reduce the second option to a fewer number of lines?

**EDIT:**

```
void Particula::move(){
// Modifies private position attributes.
    m_x += rand() % 50;
    m_y += rand() % 50;
}

void Particula::draw(){
// Draws the point given its private attributes.
    printf("Drawing circle... \n");
    // printf ("[ DEBUG:] X: %f, Y: %f, Radius: %f", m_x, m_y, m_radius);

    al_draw_filled_circle(m_x, m_y, m_radius, m_color); // Draws the point.
    al_flip_display(); // Updates the display.
}
```

The expected result is:

1. Points appear one after the other.
2. After all 25 points are drawn, clear the display.
3. Modify the attributes so as to set new coordinates.
4. Redraw all the points (or make them appear on screen) at the same time.
5. Repeat for a variable number of times (maybe 100 or 500).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the code like this did the trick:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) // being N a variable number.
{
    for (int h = 0; h < m_size; h++)
    {
        point[h].move();
        point[h].draw();
    }
    al_flip_display();
    al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0));
    al_rest(0.1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, your second code block should be executed only once, without `for` loops. Otherwise you will print the points once and once again.

> What definitely works better is ...

Under this comprehension, this is "definitely" wrong. You have to write verbose and likely-erroneous code; it is no more optimized than the `for`-loop version -- common compilers unpack loops if (it thinks) unpacking is better. (and it is usually right) Therefore by-hand unpacking is unnecessary.

Comment: It's not that unpacking is unnecessary, the second program is not the same as the first (in fact it's probably having an effect on the timing of the program, making the OP "think" it works)

Comment: In fact you cannot do it "at the same time" so OP should be seeking, fundamentally, a different approach

Answer (score 0):

As far as I read the Allegro documentation, it appears that rendering is done based on bitmap-like objects.
 Therefore, you could try to draw the points to a buffer bitmap first, something like

```
BITMAP *bmp = create_bitmap(320, 200); // make a bitmap in RAM
clear_bitmap(bmp); // zero the memory bitmap 
putpixel(bmp, x, y, color); // draw onto the memory bitmap 
blit(bmp, screen, 0, 0, 0, 0, 320, 200); // copy it to the screen
```

but for each point using a for-loop.

Note that this is just an assumption of what might work out since I have never used Allegro.

Code is copied from: http://www.allegro.free.fr/onlinedocs/en/index009.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, one can use either Bitmaps or primitives in Allegro; being a primitive a library-predefined geometric shape. For my implementation, primitives are much lighter to use, so bitmaps are discarded for now.

Comment: I see, but maybe there is another way of "pre-rendering". By drawing every point individually, you won't achieve desired results.

Comment: It puzzles me seeing calling all elements in the array 'on a row' works perfectly. If there were only 5 elements, I would consider that option... but my array is 25, and probably more in the future.

Comment: @vxlaze have you considered decoupling al_draw_filled_circle and al_flip_display. This way, you could draw all circles sequentially or simultaneoualy depending on the use-case.